# Getting list of available bluetooth devices in ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Is there a way to get list of mac addresses of available bluetooth devices in ios? I'm working on a programm which finds people nearby using bluetooth mac addresses.

Comment: Can you show what you have attempted so far

Comment: Not by MAC address but an automatically generated UUID. Also, note that there are lots of limitations but they are somewhat documented in the header files and in many-many stack overflow questions. So be ready to use google, it's your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have:

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                       options:nil];
```

That means your app is searching for BLE peripherals.

Every time your app discovers a peripheral invokes:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
 advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
              RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

You can add each discovered peripheral to an `NSArray` of `CBPeripheral`

Comment: Note that according to what the user want, you won't get the MAC Addresses, since they are hashed (with a timestamp and the own iDevice MAC Address).

Comment: Sure he can only get the Service's UUIDs from advertisementData.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not possible, as iOS does not expose the Bluetooth address to the app.

If you are using non-iOS Bluetooth peripherals, you can manually include the BD_ADDR into the *Manufacturer Info* field of the advertising data. iOS exposes this manufacturer info, and you can get the BD_ADDR from there.

For many use cases, the UUID that iOS generates for each device is sufficient. If you could provide more details (possibly in a follow-up question), there may be a good chance that a solution can be found that does not need this workaround.